# Need to know the key exchange value of the following cipher suites

Tags: key-exchange

I need to know the key exchange of the DHE-DSS cipher suites, will it be the same as mentioned in DHE-RSA?

[image]

Comment: All of these ciphersuites require (both-ephemeral) DH, but none (in TLS1.2 or below) requires any specific size such as 1024. A particular _server_ might use 1024, but another server for the same ciphersuite might not, and the same server _could_ use different sizes for different connections with the same ciphersuite (in particular, some match the DH strength to the authentication strength, which also varies). Current _good practice_ requires all non-EC (DH,DSA,RSA) be 2048 or more, and in practice only a few people do more than 2048.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these are the same key exchange: ephemeral-ephemeral Diffie-Hellman over finite fields.

Ephemeral-ephemeral is indicated by the E in DHE; it basically means that both sides should create a fresh key pair for each connection. There are certain servers that try to avoid this and only generate a key pair on startup, after a certain amount of connections or a certain time (as key pair generation is relatively expensive).

Finite field Diffie-Hellman is the original Diffie-Hellman over finite fields. This Diffie-Hellman does not use elliptic curves, but key pairs. In older implementations, this often means 1024-bit key pairs, which are now considered insecure. This is one reason why it may be a good idea to only allow ECDHE key agreement - which is also faster in most implementations. That said, it is possible to use DHE securely in TLS 1.3 sporting larger key sizes. If you allow DHE then please make sure that you only use key sizes of 2048 bit or higher.

Note that the DHE_DSS means that DSS/DSA is used for authentication. Basically, the use of DSA based certificates is non-existent, so you might as well disallow those.

Comment: Note in 1.3 keyexchange is no longer related to ciphersuite, but controlled (only) by supported_groups and signature_algorithms_* extensions -- and the former (as you indicate) in 1.3 only has FFDHE groups 2048 up and ECDHE groups 252 up.